# Importing .jar file in Ruby: how to use the class

Tags: java, ruby, jar, import, jruby

The following is my jruby file called `test.rb`

```
require 'java'
require 'jruby.jar'

java_import 'jruby.Jruby'

puts "This is coming from Ruby."
```

And this is my Java code:

```
package jruby;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Jruby {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "This is coming from Java!";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
    }   
}
```

When I run jruby using the command

```
jruby test.rb
```

the only result I get is

```
this is coming from Ruby.
```

How can I initiate from the Java class to get the code in the Jar file executed? When I try to add the following:

```
var = new Jruby()
```

it gives me an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `Jruby' for main:Object
```

**Edit**

Tried this, also didn't work. Package  name is `foo`, class name is `Foo`

```
    require 'java'
    require 'foo.jar'

    java_import 'foo.Foo'
    puts "This is coming from Ruby."
    foo.Foo.main()
```

This gave the following error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'foo' for main:Object (root) at test.rb
```

**FINAL FILE THAT WORKED WITH Meier'S HELP**

```
require 'java'
require 'foo.jar'

java_import 'javax.swing.JOptionPane'
puts "This is coming from Ruby."

import 'foo.Foo'
Java::foo::Foo.hello()
```

`hello()` being the class that contains the Java code.

Comment: you need to make sure that you do not write java syntax in ruby file, like new Jruby()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jruby, you can access java classes by package name and class name.
See https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby

Your java main method is static, so no need for `new`. So this should work.

```
jruby.Jruby.main()
```

But I suggest to rename your java class and package. You may get name clashes, as it is likely that something inside jruby is also called `jruby`.
Also the name is just wrong, because it is a java class and not a jruby class.

**Edit:**

After consulting the document, the above is only correct for standard java packages. There are several ways to access a java class:

1. use Ruby Module Syntax:

   Java::Foo::Foo.main()
2. the dot syntax, as I tried first.

> "Second way: for the top-level Java packages java, javax, javafx, org,
>   and com you can type in a fully qualified class name basically as in
>   Java, for example, java.lang.System or org.abc.def.className ..."

You either need to put your java class in the package `com.foo` or write an extra method to access the package:

```
def edu
  Java::Edu
end
```

> "And then you can use use usual Java package names like
>   edu.abc.def.ClassName"

3. after java_import, the imported Class "will be available in the global name space"

   java_import 'foo.Foo'

   Foo.main()

In all cases, you need to make sure that jruby sees the your jar file.

> " loading jar-files via require searches along the $LOAD_PATH for
>   them, like it would for normal ruby files."

Comment: This gave me the error "NameError: undefined local variable or method 'jruby' for main:Object. I will go ahead and change the names as you suggested, but I dont think that is whats causing the problem. What do you think? Thank you.

Comment: After creating a new class with a new name, I still got the same error.. So, what could the problem be? please take a look at my new test.rb file (added to the question)